# How to write multi language (string translation) webpage in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I need to show translated text on web page with TypeScript, but I don't know if there are any support for that.
My first idea was to use conditional import, but with approaches I found, I loose code completion.

```
declare var Translates: any;
switch (userLanguage)
{
    case "si":
        Translates = require('translates/si');
        break;
    default:
        Translates = require('translates/en');
        break;
}
```

I think I could write definition file and plain javascript file, but writing declaration file is time consuming, so it would be great if I could code in TypeScript.
Of course loading all translation files and returning correct string is not an option.

How can I translate my output in TypeScript and use code completion? Which approach (if any) I can use for multilanguage website in TypeScript?

*Code completion is required since there will be a lot of translations (most of them short strings - 1 or 2 words) and there is no way I can memorized them all, but opening language source file and search the name is (again) time consuming.*

Comment: are you using any framework to build your website? there usually are translation libraries that for everything. Is it really necessary that you build your own?

Comment: No library at all. Nothing, just JQuery and kendo-ui.

Comment: there is jquery-translate that you could use out of the box but it will not give you typecompletion. And I don't think of any library that does that since the the texts are usually stored in large json files. but perhaps you can use it as inspiration? https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-translate

Answer (score 0):

> How can I translate my output in TypeScript and use code completion?

Sadly you cannot do this without typing it manually e.g. `type Message = "a" | "b" | "someOtherMessage"`.

## More

The TypeScript team itself generates it from `.json` files e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json is used to generate a `diagnosticMessages.generated.ts`. This isn't locale specific but I've done similar stuff for locale checks (not open sourced sorry) in the past.